# Loading variables into function in R

Tags: r, function

I have this example data, where I load some tickers

```
libs <- c('quantmod')
lapply(libs, require, character.only = T)
tickers<-c('T','AMD','AA','AMAT','BAC')
getSymbols(tickers,from="2013-01-01")
```

Then I created function like

```
FUNtest<-function (x,y){
  data<-x
  close<-data[,y]
  return(tail(close))
}
```

which works like for example

```
FUNtest(AMD,4)
```

and the result is tail of closing prices of AMD

```
           AMD.Close
2014-07-16      4.66
2014-07-17      4.57
2014-07-18      3.83
2014-07-21      3.78
2014-07-22      3.80
2014-07-23      3.76
```

But, for later usage, I need to be able to use function this way

```
FUNtest(tickers[2],4)
```

but it doesn't work. If I call

```
tickers[2]
```

it shows

```
> tickers[2]
[1] "AMD"
```

but it is not able to work in function. And advices how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `get` in the function.

`get("AMD")` finds `AMD` in the evaluation frame (or not) and returns the value attached to it.

```
> FUNtest<-function (x,y){
     data<-get(x)
     close<-data[,y]
     return(tail(close))
 }
> FUNtest(tickers[2], 4)
#            AMD.Close
# 2014-07-16      4.66
# 2014-07-17      4.57
# 2014-07-18      3.83
# 2014-07-21      3.78
# 2014-07-22      3.80
# 2014-07-23      3.76
```

Also, there isn't really a need to use `return` here.  This function might be better for you

```
> f <- function(x, y){ x <- get(x); tail(x[, y], 3) }
## on the entire tickers vector, get column 4 and bind them
> do.call(cbind, lapply(tickers, f, y = 4))
#            T.Close AMD.Close AA.Close AMAT.Close BAC.Close
# 2014-07-16   36.45      4.66    16.60      22.85     15.51
# 2014-07-17   36.03      4.57    16.33      22.77     15.20
# 2014-07-18   36.17      3.83    16.49      23.00     15.49
```

`eval` can also be quite useful for unquoted arguments

```
> f <- function(x){ eval(x) }
> head(f(AMD), 3)
#            AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume AMD.Adjusted
# 2013-01-02     2.55     2.57    2.45      2.53   27214800         2.53
# 2013-01-03     2.52     2.59    2.46      2.49   24966900         2.49
# 2013-01-04     2.51     2.59    2.49      2.59   22054200         2.59
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between

```
FUNtest(AMD,4)
```

and

```
FUNtest("AMD",4)
```

With the former, you are passing a `name` which points to an `xts` object. In the latter, you are simply passing a character string. This string is in no way directly connected to the object of the same name.

If you want a function that works if you pass a character or an `xts` object, you can do

```
FUNtest<-function (x,y){
  if(is(x, "xts")) {
      data <- x
  } else if (is(x, "character")) {
      data <- get(x)
  } else {
    stop(paste("invalid x class:", class(x)))
  }
  close <- data[,y]
  return(tail(close))
}
```

then both

```
FUNtest(AMD, 4)
FUNtest(tickers[2], 4)
```

will work.

But even better is not to use the behavior of `quantmod` where it adds variables to your global environment. This is the default that's being phased out because it encourages bad behavior. It's better to store them all in a list like

```
symb<-lapply(setNames(tickers, tickers), function(x) 
    getSymbols(x,from="2013-01-01",  auto.assign=F))
```

Then you can have `symb$AMAT` or `symb[["AMAT"]]` depending on how you want to extract the data. The latter form is more flexible because you can specify a variable with a particular value or you can perform an action to all the data.sets by `lapply`-ing over the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're passing a dataframe called `AMD`; in the second you're just passing a  character value `"AMD"`.

I'm guessing that the dataframe `AMD` is already loaded into your work space so that's why `FUNtest` works in the first case.

if you want the function to work try either passing the data frame you want to the function, or tell the function where to find the data frame you want.

Comment: “One way is via the `deparse(substitute(x))` trick.” – that would give you `tickers[2]` here; not what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks, can you specifiy the format of usage? I am trying FUNtest(deparse(substitute(tickers[2])),4) and it still doesn't work

Comment: ah, whoops you're right Konrad. the get() function is the proper choice here, but it assumes that whatever `tickers[2]` is calling exists somewhere in the workspace.